# What does the @ symbol do in iPython/Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook, zipline

A code that I'm reading uses `@batch_transform`. What does the `@` symbol do? Is it ipython specific?

```
from zipline.transforms import batch_transform
from scipy import stats

@batch_transform
def regression_transform(data):
    pep_price = data.price['PEP']
    ko_price = data.price['KO']
    slope, intercept, _, _, _ = stats.linregress(pep_price, ko_price)

    return intercept, slope
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@` syntax signals that `batch_transform` is a Python decorator, read more about it in the [wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), quoting:

> A Python decorator is a specific change to the Python syntax that allows us to more conveniently alter functions and methods (and possibly classes in a future version). This supports more readable applications of the DecoratorPattern but also other uses as well

Also take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#function):

> A function definition may be wrapped by one or more decorator expressions. Decorator expressions are evaluated when the function is defined, in the scope that contains the function definition. The result must be a callable, which is invoked with the function object as the only argument. The returned value is bound to the function name instead of the function object. Multiple decorators are applied in nested fashion

Comment: Epic answer on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python

Answer (score 1):

It is a decorator. A Python decorator.

Function, method, or class definitions may be preceded by a `@` special symbol known as a decorator, the purpose of which is to modify the behavior of the definition that follows.

Decorators are denoted with the @ symbol and must be placed on a separate line immediately before the corresponding function, method, or class. Here’s an example:

```
class Foo(object):
    @staticmethod
    def bar():
        pass
```

Also, you can have multiple decorators:

```
@span
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

Here is a [good lesson](http://www.learnpython.org/Decorators) on it. Here is a [great thread on it for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

any function can be wrapped using a `decorator` by `@` symbol

example

```
def decor(fun):
    def wrapper():
        print "Before function call"
        print fun()
        print "Before function call"
    return wrapper

@decor
def my_function():
    return "Inside Function"

my_function()


## output ##
Before function call
Inside Function
Before function call
```

[NOTE] even `classmethod` and `staticmethod`'s are implemented using decorators in `python`

In your case, there would be function called `batch_transform`, and you have `imported` it !

Comment: I think you mean `return wrapper`, or else you will create... a black hole or something.

Comment: @rodrigo, yes you are right